# When a question is closed because its duplicate, why should it have -1 or +1 button?

Tags: feature-request

I have posted a question which turned out to be a duplicate.

Here is my drab experience:

1. I quickly admitted myself its a duplicate within 1 hour of further research.
2. I voted to delete the question & flagged the admin requesting immediate delete (I didnt know it was not possible at that time).
3. There were 3 users (in the period of 24 hrs) who -1 my question and added a comment saying its a dupe (way after I posted it was a dupe near the heading of the question by editing it).

**So, when a question is closed because its' duplicate, why should it have -1 or +1 button?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, when a question is closed because its' duplicate, why should it have -1 or +1 button?

One reason is that most people aren't as diligent as you, and do no research - neither before, nor after asking their question. Voting can serve as feedback for those people.

I agree what you describe is really unfair, but never mind. Just ignore the vote and go on.

Comment: but allowing -1 - isnt it an overkill?

Comment: @Pandey what makes duplicate questions so special that downvoting should be forbidden on them, as opposed to *every other* question on the network that isn't deleted? You're going to get unfair downvotes from time to time, on open questions as well as closed ones. It happens to everyone. Don't worry about it.

Comment: no no that wont stop anyone from contributing to this wonderful network :) no doubt in that! lets say the question is closed and not deleted for a period of 2 months, each time one sweet evil genius feels he landed on some BS and gives it -1 is like reminding you a mistake that u did when u went to school ;) its like karma theory! but i am looking for redemption :) dont we all? :) i can assure u that i dont worry abt it :) just concerned to improvise...

Comment: @Pandey just ignore the downvotes. Everyone gets them from time to time. Why implement a complicated feature to prevent downvotes in one specific rare situation?

Comment: i agree with u more and more after each comment because i myself saw many low quality duplicates in this process and much worse posting random stuff just to catch the eye. its already a beautiful place u need strong rules to keep it that way. i accept ur answer as correct!

Answer (score 4):

When I look for information, Google often leads me to duplicate questions. If the questions that it's a dup of is helpful, I often like to thank the author of  dup question as well by a +1.

Dups are useful because not everybody words their questions the same ... why not repay this with a +1?

Comment: good positive thinking there!